# T-SQL Pivot table not using IN and values from another column in the pivot data based on MIN() & MAX

Tags: sql, sql-server, t-sql, pivot-table

I have a pivot table problem & would love help....

The tutorials I'm following aren't helping as they use an IN statement on a known list of values to create the columns.

It's my IN statement I might be stuck on...I'm trying a subquery, but it's not helping.

```
SELECT 
    JobDesc, YearExp
FROM
    (SELECT JobDesc, YearExp, Worker 
     FROM Q2) AS SourceTable
PIVOT 
    (MIN(YearExp)
        FOR YearExp IN (SELECT YearExp FROM Q2)
    ) AS PivotTable
```

The data:

| Worker | Job Description | Years of Experience |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 1001 | Lawyer | 6 |
| 2002 | Lawyer | 12 |
| 3003 | Lawyer | 17 |
| 4004 | Doctor | 21 |
| 5005 | Doctor | 9 |
| 6006 | Doctor | 8 |
| 7007 | Scientist | 13 |
| 8008 | Scientist | 2 |
| 9009 | Scientist | 7 |

The output I'm trying to achieve:

| Job Description | Most Experienced | Least Experienced |
| --- | --- | --- |
| Lawyer | 3003 | 1001 |
| Doctor | 4004 | 6006 |
| Scientist | 7007 | 8008 |

Comment: You can't use a subquery or any other kind of expression, it has to be literals

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The window function `row_number() over()` in concert with a conditional aggregation should do the trick

```
Select [Job Description]
      ,[Most]  = max( case when RN1 = 1 then worker end)
      ,[Least] = max( case when RN2 = 1 then worker end)
 From (
        Select * 
              ,RN1 = row_number() over (partition by [Job Description] order by [Years of Experience] desc)
              ,RN2 = row_number() over (partition by [Job Description] order by [Years of Experience] asc)
         from YourTable
      ) A
 Group By [Job Description]
```

**Results**

```
Job Description  Most   Least
Doctor           4004   6006
Lawyer           3003   1001
Scientist        7007   8008
```

Answer (score 1):

The `PIVOT` operator is rather inflexible, and requires a fixed list of columns to pivot.

The [answer given by @JohnCappelletti](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70238077/14868997) is good, but it has the downside of requiring an extra sort because of the opposing row-number.

Here is a solution that only requires one sort

```sql
Select [Job Description]
      ,[Most]  = max( case when NextValue IS NULL then worker end)
      ,[Least] = max( case when RN = 1 then worker end)
 From (
        Select * 
              ,RN = row_number() over (partition by [Job Description] order by [Years of Experience] asc)
              ,NextVal = LEAD([Years of Experience]) over (partition by [Job Description] order by [Years of Experience] asc)
         from YourTable
      ) A
 Group By [Job Description]
```

The value inside the `LEAD` must be a non-nullable value.